# How to return time index after reaching some threshold in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

If I have a Pandas data frame that includes time and distance traveled for example that looks like this:

```
2017-03-05 11:46:08 0
2017-03-05 11:46:09 1.3
2017-03-05 11:46:10 2.1
2017-03-05 11:46:11 3.6
2017-03-05 11:46:12 4.2
2017-03-05 11:46:13 5.3
2017-03-05 11:46:14 6.8
2017-03-05 11:46:15 7.1
2017-03-05 11:46:16 8.8
2017-03-05 11:46:17 9.2
2017-03-05 11:46:18 10.1
2017-03-05 11:46:19 11.1
2017-03-05 11:46:20 12.3
2017-03-05 11:46:21 13.5
2017-03-05 11:46:22 14.2
2017-03-05 11:46:23 15.2
```

I want to return the time of every time we reach approximately 5 such that we return an array of time that looks like this

```
 np.array([2017-03-05 11:46:13,  2017-03-05 11:46:18, 2017-03-05 11:46:23])
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"approximately 5"* ? You need to specify a measure

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column names are `['Date', 'col']` , you can do:

```
df.groupby(divmod(df['col'],5)[0])['Date'].first().ravel()
```

Where:

```
print(df.groupby(divmod(df['col'],5)[0])['Date'].first())
```

---

```
col
0.0   2017-03-05 11:46:08
1.0   2017-03-05 11:46:13
2.0   2017-03-05 11:46:18
3.0   2017-03-05 11:46:23
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Note, check the dtype of the first column. If its not a datetime, convert it using

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```